# How to talk to a Java servlet from a Native IOS App

Tags: java, ios, stripes

we made a HTML5 mobile app, & now we are creating a IOS native App. We want the IOS app to call methods on the Java servlet (with stripes) (running the HTML5 App) so that we can use the same behind-the-scenes logic. Do we need to setup a web service to do this?

I.E we would like to just call the existing Stripes action beans from IOS (as they are already set up to receive ajax requests, but will this violate the cross-domain law)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-domain isn't an issue if you're making requests from a native app, so it should be possible to make requests to your AJAX ActionBeans directly.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly call the logic by using API and get the response. Do servlet mapping to the url pattern you need. then in servlet extend the HttpServlet and override doGet and doPost method, which has HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse as input parameters, which can be used to communicate with your mobile app.

Comment: The OP is using Stripes framework, so he's already got servlets in place. He's not asking about that, he's asking about how to access those servlets from an iOS app.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that he has the servlet and my core answer is to make an API call , read the request through HttpServletRequest object and return the response through HttpServletResponse . It would be just like calling a link with query string.